# Prove cardinality of a finite set is different than that of its power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was hoping someone could check my work and confirm whether it's a valid proof by induction.

For this problem we're allowed to use that $\left|P(A)\right|$ = $2^\left|A\right|$ for part of our proof

We want to prove $\left|P(A)\right|$ > $\left|A\right|$ for any finite set

That is that: $2^\left|A\right|$ > $\left|A\right|$

Base case $\left|A\right|$ = 1

$2^1$ > $1$, therefore this relation holds for $\left|A\right|$ = 1

Let us assume that the relation is true for the value $n = k$

That is that $2^k$ > $k$

For $2^{k+1} > k + 1$ we can rearrange this algebraically to get

2 > $({k + 1})^{1 / (k + 1)}$

lim k → ∞ $({k + 1})^{1 / (k + 1)} = 1$

As such, it is true that $2^{k+1} > k + 1$

Therefore $\left|P(A)\right|$ > $\left|A\right|$ and as such $\left|P(A)\right|$ != $\left|A\right|$

Comment: Is it required to prove it by induction?

Comment: It's suggested, but not required. That said, I'd like to know if the proof is valid, not whether or not there's an alternative way to do it.

Comment: Let assume that $2^k > k$....

Answer (score 2):

No, your proof's not valid. Yes, it's true that $\lim_{k\to\infty}(k+1)^{1/(k+1)}=1$, but this doesn't imply $(k+1)^{1/(k+1)}<2$ for all $k$. It's much easier to note $2^k>k\implies2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^k>2k\ge k+1$ provided $k\ge1$, giving an inductive step that works for $k\ge1$. We then just need $k=0,\,k=1$ to both be include in the base case.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that $2^{k+1}$ = $2 * 2^k$ and that we're saying $2^k > k$ so we have $2 * 2^k$ > $k + 1$ but I'm not fully understanding where the $2k$ comes from

Comment: @PDef From $x>y\implies2x>2y$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use that $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}$ things can become easier than in the proof you show. We must show that $2^{|A|}>|A|$, or what is equivalent, that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, $2^{k}>k$ (where $|A|=k$; I do not know why you haven't considered the case $|A|=0$, but this one is quite simple, so I will ignore it).

- Base case: $k=1$

In this case, $2^{k}=2^{1}=2$, which is greater than $k=1$.

- Induction hypothesis: assume the result holds for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $j\geq 1$

Then, $2^{j+1}=2.2^{j}$, and since $2^{j}>j$ (by induction hypothesis), we obtain
$$2^{j+1}=2.2^{j}>2.j\geq j+1$$
(where $2.j\geq j+1$ since $j\geq 1$), meaning $2^{j+1}>j+1$. This ends the proof by induction that $|\mathcal{P}(A)|>|A|$ whenever $A$ is a finite, non-empty set.

Notice, however, that this is not the standard proof of such a result: one shows that $|\mathcal{P}(A)|\geq |A|$ by considering the injective function $f:A\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A)$ taking an element $a\in A$ to the singleton $\{a\}$; one then shows that we cannot have $|A|\geq|\mathcal{P}(A)|$ (and therefore $|\mathcal{P}(A)|>|A|$) by a diagonal argument à la Cantor.